# Why isn't Openshift installing the pg gem that's in my gemfile?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, openshift, ramaze

My gemfile for my [Ramaze](http://ramaze.net) (rack) app looks like this.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'ramaze', "<= 2012.04.14" #old version
    gem "innate", ">= 2012.03", "< 2012.11" #old version
    gem 'rack', "<= 1.4.1"
gem 'sequel'
#if defined? ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'production' then gem 'pg' else gem 'sqlite3' end
gem 'pg'
gem "sentry-raven", :git => "https://github.com/coderanger/raven-ruby.git"
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'   
gem 'rdiscount' 
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'pony'
gem 'bacon'
gem 'koala'
gem 'stop_forum_spam'

#source 'http://mirror1.prod.rhcloud.com/mirror/ruby/'
#gem 'nokogiri'
#gem 'capybara'
```

As you can see, the pg gem is defined in it. However when I do a git push on [Openshift](http://openshift.com), it installs every gem on my gem file EXCEPT for `pg`. I've done `bundle install` on my computer before a push with a `force_clean_build` file in the `.openshift` folder, and it didn't help.

I'm using the [Sequel ORM](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) and aren't even using a postgres database in my app, so changing the subject, I've no idea why it wants the `pg` gem in the first place.

Comment: What is the error you are showing that makes you think the pg gem is not installed?

Comment: I checked the logs, `ruby.log`, I scrolled down the the bottom of the file, and that was the most recent log, unless I have to check another log. I'll do that now.

Comment: I checked all the logs and that's the only error, the pg not being installed.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Windows?

Try looking at this:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1126343

Comment: Yes I am using Windows. Out of interest, how did you know about the bug? This question has just 8 views, so what's the chances someone could know about the bug?